# Reaching a controller in multiple folders

Tags: php, laravel

I have defined a controller inside this location `App\Http\Controllers\UserPortal\PlainVersion;`

and this is the controller

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Controllers\UserPortal\PlainVersion;

class UserPortalController extends Controller
{
     public function my_account()
    {
        return view('userportal\htmlversion\my_account');
    }
```

**This is my web.php**

```
<?php
//UserPortal landing
Route::get('my_account', 'UserPortal\PlainVersion\UserPortalController@my_account');
//Route::get('ma_ajax', 'UserPortal\PhpVersion\UserPortalController@my_account_ajax');
```

However even after running `composer dump-autoload` i keep getting this error

> Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
>   Target class [App\Http\Controllers\UserPortal\PlainVersion\UserPortalController] does not exist.
>   http://localhost:8000/my_account

Why do i keep getting this error? I am using laravel 6.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace specified within the controller class needs to match the path the file lives at.

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\UserPortal\PlainVersion;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class UserPortalController extends Controller
{
     public function my_account()
    {
        return view('userportal\htmlversion\my_account');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the controller namespace should be

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\UserPortal\PlainVersion
```

I have the same problem previously and that fixed it.

Comment: is this class `App\Http\Controllers\UserPortal\PlainVersion` exist ? If it just a folder you shouldn't have to `use` it

Answer (score 0):

This worked but i welcome comments on why it did

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\UserPortal\PlainVersion;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

//use App\Http\Controllers\UserPortal\PlainVersion;

class UserPortalController extends Controller
{
     public function my_account()
    {
        return view('userportal\htmlversion\my_account');
    }
```

Comment: The namespace and path names matching are what allow file autoloading to work. PHP sees the requirement for App\Http\Controllers\UserPortal\PlainVersion\UserPortalController in the route, coverts it into a path automatically, and tries to load that file. https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/